# can't find error in program which will remove duplicate numbers from array

Tags: c, arrays

Problem statement : remove duplicate number from array and again print it 
My approach is 
 1. compare number with all other and find duplicate
 2. send index of duplicate to the function delindex and shift all numbers by one and decrement index size by one. 
Problem is 18 is not shifting.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a[20]={11,12,13,15,12,14,16,17,11,12,14,15,18,12},i,j,index=13,x,y,p;
void delindex(int n)
{
    int i,j,ii;
    if(n==index)
    {
        index--;
    }
    else
    {   
        for(i=n;n<index;n++)
        {
            j=i+1;
            a[i]=a[j];
        }
    index--;            
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=index;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(x=0;x<index;x++)
    {
            for(y=x+1;y<=index;y++)
            {
                if(a[x]==a[y])
                {
                    delindex(y);
                }
            }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=index;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }   
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: None of the variables that are global should be global.  They should all be local to the functions, and you should pass the array to the function, along with its size.  You should probably initialize `index` with `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) - 1` so that if/when you add entries to the array, or remove them, you can simply recompile without having to remember to adjust `index` explicitly too.  And declare one variable per line.  And global variables should have a comment explaining their significance — if they aren't significant (`i`, `x`, `y`, `p`, etc) then they shouldn't be global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the line `for(i=n;n<index;n++)` in `void delindex(int n)` should be `for (int i = n; i < index; ++i)`
2. the line

```
for(y=x+1;y<=index;y++)
{
    if(a[x]==a[y])
    {
        delindex(y);
    }
}
```

should be

```
for(y=x+1;y<=index;)
{
    if(a[x]==a[y])
    {
        delindex(y);
    } else {
        ++y;
    }
}
```

for `a[] = {1, 2, 1, 1}` before code will be `{1, 2, 1}`

the following `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = {11, 12, 13, 15, 12, 14, 16, 17, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 12};
int index = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) - 1;

void delindex(int n) {
  if (n == index) {
    --index;
  } else {
    for (int i = n; i < index; ++i) a[i] = a[i + 1];
    index--;
  }
}

int main() {
  printf("before remove duplicate\n");
  for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i) printf("%d\t", a[i]);
  printf("\n");
  for (int x = 0; x < index; ++x)
    for (int y = x + 1; y <= index;)
      if (a[x] == a[y])
        delindex(y);
      else
        ++y;
  printf("after remove duplicate\n");
  for (int i = 0; i <= index; ++i) printf("%d\t", a[i]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion .... code is working properly.........................

Answer (score -1):

Actually your code is working fine, just take care of some things. I will list them out here.

1. Don't use 'index' as a variable name, it is a built-in function.
2. If a variable is declared globally in C you need not declare it locally. If you do the local variable value is only modified, the global one remains untouched.

You are printing the final result before giving a newline, that combined with the final result of delindex is confusing you. I have provided an updated version of the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a[20]={11,12,13,15,12,14,16,17,11,12,14,15,18,12},i,j,ind=13,x,y,p;
void delindex(int n)
{
    int i,j,ii;
    if(n==ind)
    {
        ind--;
    }
    else
    {   
        for(i=n;n<ind;n++)
        {
            j=i+1;
            a[i]=a[j];
        }
        ind--;            
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(ii=0;ii<=ind;ii++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[ii]);
    }   
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=ind;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(x=0;x<ind;x++)
    {
        for(y=x+1;y<=ind;y++)
        {
            if(a[x]==a[y])
            {
                delindex(y);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nFinal Result: \n");
    for(i=0;i<=ind;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a[i]);
    }   
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I have executed your code but it give following output :

Comment: output is 
11      12      13      15      14      16      17
Final Result:
11      12      13      15      14      16      17     But still 18 is not printing ....................